# Problem connecting to Postgres

Tags: orange

I want to use the SQL table connector to link data in a PostGres database which is on my local machine running as 9.6. When I do this I get the following error;

```
could not open extension control file ".../postgressql/extension/quantile.control" No such file or directory
```

Looking so some similar issues I  tried:

```
find /usr -name quantile.control
```

in terminal and get:

```
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
```

What can I do to resolve this?

EDIT: From this [answer](https://blog.biolab.si/2015/12/04/2uda/) I can see tat I need to install an extension, which I do according to the instructions [here](https://pgxn.org/dist/quantile). But am not able to get the extension to install getting the following error:

```
INFO: best version: quantile 1.1.5
INFO: saving /var/folders/0c/g8tsv9jx3qgdwrdpqvjx45tr0000gn/T/tmppe1b4shp/quantile-1.1.5.zip
INFO: unpacking: /var/folders/0c/g8tsv9jx3qgdwrdpqvjx45tr0000gn/T/tmppe1b4shp/quantile-1.1.5.zip
INFO: building extension
Makefile:16: /Applications/anaconda/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/Applications/anaconda/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.
```